# using JTextField for user input database table names in select query

Tags: java

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try {
        String sql =" select * from  '"+name+"' ";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
            pst.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

I am using user input in `string sql="select * from '"+name+"'"` name textfield but it is giving error. But instead of name when I enter table name it shows but not taking table name through name textfield.

Comment: Is your name variable holding the correct value. Could you try debugging or printing your name value on console?

Comment: Type of `name` is `String` or `JTextField`?

Answer (score 0):

just like this assign input field's value to name string. 
  jTextField1 means the textfield that holds the name..

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
try {
    String name= jTextField1.getText();
    String sql =" select * from  '"+name+"' ";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
}
catch(Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
finally {
    try {
        rs.close();
        pst.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you're using `PreparedStatment`s, why aren't you utilizing parameters?

Answer (score 0):

In select statement the '"+name+"' used is a string getting a jTextField value. So, use following SQL statement to fetch table from textfield value.

```
String s1 = jTextField1.getText();
    try
  {
      Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default","arunachalam", "");
      Statement st = con.createStatement();

      String sql = "select * from " + s1;                
       int rs = st.executeUpdate(sql);

      showMessageDialog(null,"Query Executed");

   }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      showMessageDialog(null,e);
  }
```

Leave a space after from and then do the statement. Assign what variable name you were using for your textfield, this will work.
Use alternative class driver and connection statement that you were using in your code.